# Enable Aspect proxy based on runtime condition, Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using Spring AOP to reduce my debug log of my existing application.

What I tried to do is log every method invocation based on log level.

I know Spring will construct a proxy for every class of mine if I using below aspect,which will introduce some overhead if it is not in debug level:

```
package com.basepackage.aop;

import....

@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAspect {

    private Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(LogAspect.class.getName());

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.basepackage..*.*(..))")//all the method in my app
    private void debug_log(){};

    @Around("debug_log()")//here, I hope I can introduce something like && logger.isDebugeEnable()
    public Object aroundLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        String signature=joinPoint.getSignature().toString();
        String paramList = null;
        Object[] args=joinPoint.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            paramList+=args[i]+" ";
        }

        String debugMsg="----------enter "+signature;
        if(paramList!=null){
            debugMsg+="\nparam: "+paramList;
        }

        LogUtil.debug(debugMsg);//will delegate to log4j
        try{
            Object returnObject= joinPoint.proceed();
            LogUtil.debug("--------return form"+signature);//will delegate to log4j
            return returnObject;
        }
        catch(Throwable t){
            LogUtil.error("--------error from "+signature, t);//will delegate to log4j
            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

What I hope is that only when log4j level <=debug level will Spring AOP construct a proxy for every class.

Or any more suggestion on how to make the log clean will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an activation condition to your pointcut via `if()`, see [AspectJ documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697). The pointcut then returns `boolean` instead of `void` and contains a body dynamically evaluating the condition and returning the result:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.basepackage..*.*(..)) && if()")
public boolean debug_log() {
    return logger.isdebugEnabled();
};
```

Because it is dynamic, I guess the proxies are still being created, but the advice body will not be executed. In order to get rid of the proxies, switch from Spring AOP to AspectJ which does not use proxies and is more efficient. AspectJ can be easily integrated into Apring applications via LTW (load-time weaving).

**Update:**

Spring AOP is just a proxy-based "AOP lite" approach for method interception, not a full-fledged framework like AspectJ. Thus, it does not support the `if()` pointcut primitive, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). Having said that, I suggest you switch to full AspectJ. It can be applied to Spring applications easily via LTW (load-time weaving) as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Comment: Thank you! I will try ! But I have one more thing to ask, does the `logger` have something need to pay attention to? For example: does it has to be non-static, or where does it has to be created from(injected , constructor or something else)?

Comment: I got some error when I run the application in tomcat, the nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: Pointcut expression 'execution(* wodinow.weixin.jaskey..*.*(..)) && if()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'if'

Comment: The logger can be static if you wish. This question is unrelated to the AOP problem.

Comment: So dou you mean there is no other way to maje a point cut based on run time cindition using spring aop？

Comment: Correct. If I had known one, I would have told you.